# Resize / crop images for android devices (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resize, crop, minimagick

I need to resize/crop images in different resolutions for Android App.

I know, that it's a common question, but I could not find a solution that would suit for me.

The problem is consist in the fact that different devices had *different* diagonal. The administrator upload to CMS only one image with size 668x1024 (for example). Then I need to send a picture to the device with such resolutions: 400x600, 540x960, etc. I can't just resize each image, because on the phone would appear a background-lines.

So, I'm or violating the aspect ratio (that's not good because picture becomes ugly) or should to crop the image. But because of the different proportions it's hard to do.

I tried ***mini-magick*** and *[g1nn13-image-science](http://rubygems.org/gems/g1nn13-image_science)*, but in the first one I can't take the current images width and height (and because of it I can't realize the cropping algorithm) and the second one gives me an error when I try to require image_science: "no such file to load -- inline"

All help and advices appreciated: some decisions about How To do it (maybe not to do cropping, but some another decision?) or gems that could help me.

Thanks.

**ANSWER:**
I used [fastimage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) gem for finding picture's current height and width and the method of [minimagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick) gem *image.shave*.

Example:

```
current_w, current_h = FastImage.size(object.attach.path)
if current_w < current_h
  remove_h = ((current_h - height)/2).round
  image.shave("0x#{remove_h}")
  remove_w = ((current_w - width)/2).round
  image.shave("#{remove_w}x0")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good gem called dragonfly for rack apps.

Basically you save base image, and then you can pass resolution in the request, and it saves new size in the cache.

Here is some introduction to this [gem](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/1/2/dragonfly)

Overview:

Android ==(400x600)=> Rails(ImagesController#show) ===> image_url(400x600).jpg

Comment: Is it important to run a [handler](http://www.pastie.org/2882986) that described in a rack config.ru? Because I don't see it in the manual that dedicated to this gem on [github](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly). And when I try to run this [handler](http://www.pastie.org/2882986) I have an error "uninitialized constant Dragonfly::RMagickConfiguration (NameError)" config.ru:13

Comment: Have you tried this doc: https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/extra_docs/Rails3.md

Comment: and it seems, that Dragonfly model accessor not working for my app, because of Paperclip attachments uploading...

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer. Remove all your paperclip code and just use dragonfly, failing that try and get dragonfly working in a new rails project with nothing else in it as your getting some pretty weird errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use paperclip, it uses ImageMagick and allows to specify its cropping algorithm, for example:

```
400x600^
400x600#
400x600>
```

The `^` `#` and `>` are described [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: _"400x600^400x600#400x600>"_ what is it?
Papercip allows to make cropping in time of attaching with the help of :croppable option, as I understood. And I need to do cropping when I want to do it. Can you give me some code-example how can I crop an image in Console? From the file opening by PATH and to the moment of saving picture with using of Paperclip?

Comment: Yes, paperclip crops images on set, i.e. once. This is good as you can create, for example, 50 styles and make this heavy cropping once. All other calls will return static image.

Comment: but if I don't know what styles I will need? I know them only after time, when device sends me request with height and width params.

Comment: You can create a set of common used styles, as you dont need to crop image from 100x100 to 100x99 if client requested

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fits your needs,
http://www.gra2.com/article.php/using-rmagick-imagemagick-rails

if you don`t want to use any gem you can reach the installed programms with the rails

`system`

command.